# Repeat Higher Order Function

Tags: python

I'm writing a Higher Order that takes a lambda expression, a number, then number of times it has to repeat that. This is what I have:

```
#Square Root
sqrt = lambda x: x ** (1/2)

#Repeat
def repeat(f,x,r):
    return [f(i) for r in x]
```

Here's what it should do:

```
>>> repeat(sqrt, 2, 0)
2
>>> repeat(sqrt, 2, 1)
1.4142135623730951
>>> repeat(sqrt, 2, 2)
1.189207115002721
```

Here's the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "main.py", line 66, in repeat
    return [f(i) for r in x]
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

This is NOT a repeat because I am asking how to fix MY code, not how to do the problem. Also this is NOT homework, it is simply a project to understand higher order functions better.

Comment: What happens? Show output or error (traceback) as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Did you try writing a `for` loop? Also note that you do not have to write a lambda function. You can pass any regular function as an argument.

Comment: I'll provide an error message, and I'm not sure how to write a for loop for this.

Comment: The code you posted produces `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`.  That's because `x` is 2, and you have `... for r in x`.  Since 2 is not an iterable, it's an error.  Not sure what the intent was.  Did you mean `range(x)`?

Comment: Like this: `for i in range(r): ... something with f(x)`

Comment: So `repeat(sqrt, 2, 2) == sqrt(sqrt(2))`? Recursion is useful here, though a loop would be more efficient.

Comment: Also, the value passed in as `r` is unused in `repeat`, so why have it as an argument at all?

Comment: There appears to be some confusion surrounding list comprehensions and iterables, the issue is unrelated to the use of higher ordered functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work if you used a for loop.

```
#Square Root
sqrt = lambda x: x ** (1/2)

#Repeat
def repeat(f,x,r):
    for i in range(r):
        x = f(x)
    return x

print(repeat(sqrt, 2, 2))
```

Comment: Whoops, the x in range is supposed to be r

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension is not the right tool here. You want a single value — a list comprehension *always* creates a list.

Since this seems like an exercise, in keeping with the style of lambdas and higher order functions, you could recurse with something like:

```
sqrt = lambda x: x ** (1/2)

rep = lambda f, x, r: f(x) if r < 1 else f(rep(f, x, r - 1))

rep(sqrt, 2, 0)
# 1.4142135623730951
rep(sqrt, 2, 1)
# 1.189207115002721
```

If `r` will be large, you may have issues with recursion depth, however.

You could also use `functools.reduce`

```
from functools import reduce

sqrt = lambda x: x ** (1/2)

rep = lambda f, x, r: reduce(lambda n, _: f(n), range(r+1), x)

rep(sqrt, 2, 0)
# 1.4142135623730951

rep(sqrt, 2, 1)
# 1.189207115002721
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Square Root
sqrt = lambda x: x ** (1/2)

#Repeat
def repeat(f,x,r):

    if r > 0:
        return repeat(f,f(x),r-1)
    else: 
        return x
```

---

```
print(repeat(sqrt, 2, 2))
>> 1.189207115002721
```

a solution using recursion

Answer (score -1):

```
def repeat(f,x,r): 
    return [f(i) for r in range(x)]
```

You are trying to iterate number which is not possible